# RxJava - Why Do We Need BehaviorSubject, ASyncSubject, and ReplaySubject?

Tags: java, rx-java, reactive-programming, reactivex

I am hammering out some documentation on RxJava, and I realized I have a question. Why do we even need a `BehaviorSubject`, `ASyncSubject`, and `ReplaySubject`? Can we not just use a `PublishSubject` and simply follow it with the right operators to create these behaviors?

For instance, `BehaviorSubject` looks like it can be replicated using a `replay(1).autoConnect()`. I think you can more or less use operators to accomplish the policies of the other Subjects too, using `replay(1).autoConnect().take(1)` for `ASyncSubject`, and maybe simply `cache()` for `ReplaySubject`.

```
import io.reactivex.Observable;
import io.reactivex.subjects.AsyncSubject;
import io.reactivex.subjects.BehaviorSubject;
import io.reactivex.subjects.Subject;

public class Launcher {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Subject<String> subject =
                BehaviorSubject.<String>create().toSerialized();

        Observable<String> cacheLast =
                subject.replay(1).autoConnect();

        cacheLast.subscribe(s -> System.out.println("Observer 1: " + s));

        subject.onNext("Alpha");
        subject.onNext("Beta");
        subject.onNext("Gamma");

        cacheLast.subscribe(s -> System.out.println("Observer 2: " + s));
    }
}
```

Comment: If you read their code, you'll see that they behave in slightly different ways.

Comment: I suppose there is the eagerness aspect...